# When is recordZoneWithIDWasPurgedBlock and recordZoneWithIDWasDeletedBlock called?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

`CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` has `recordZoneWithIDWasPurgedBlock` and `recordZoneWithIDWasDeletedBlock` blocks. My assumption is that when the user deletes all iCloud data associated to an app the purge block is called, and when I manually delete a zone then the delete block is called.

However in my experience of a few weeks with CloudKit neither have ever been called, I have tried many methods to trigger either block but it never happens. Instead these scenarios seem to be handled through errors in the `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation` I later make. I get a `CKError.Code.changeTokenExpired` if the zone has been deleted and a `CKError.Code.userDeletedZone` if the user deletes iCloud data themselves.

Handling these scenarios through errors is fine and manageable for me but leaves me wondering when are these blocks ever called? Should I be handling them the same way I handle the errors for deleted/purged zones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug of my own doing caused the custom zone to always be created at app launch which would obviously never trigger delete blocks AND invalidate all change tokens.

I have the most frustrating type of advice for those having a similar issue: check your code! Make sure you're not creating the custom zone before you fetch database changes.